# FCM send push to device group returns 'messaging/invalid-recipient'

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hi I am trying to use `Firebase Cloud Functions` to send push notifications via `FCM` to a device group like this:

```
// Send a message to the device group corresponding to the provided
// notification key.
admin.messaging().sendToDeviceGroup(notification_key, payload)
.then(function(response) {
// See the MessagingDeviceGroupResponse reference documentation for
// the contents of response.
    console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
})
.catch(function(error) {
   console.log("Error sending message:", error);
   });
}
```

The console returns me :

```
{ code: 'messaging/invalid-recipient',
 message: 'Notification key provided to sendToDeviceGroup() is invalid.' } }
```

The `notification_key` I use is : `const notification_key = "APA91bG09Lqs...rb48dE5hs";`
and is the `notification_key` that gets returned in the response when I create a device group

Comment: I notice that you have `const notificationKey = "APA91bG09Lqs...rb48dE5hs";` **but** then have `sendToDeviceGroup(notification_key, payload)`. Shouldn't it be `sendToDeviceGroup(notificationKey, payload)`?

Comment: true...it is like that ... my bad when writing the question ... will edit to clear the mistake

Comment: well ... what I am passing is the value received when creating the device group. When I create a group I received a response of form `notification_key: "APA91bG09Lqs...rb48dE5hs"` -> that i ultimately store in my db as a reference together with the `notification_key_name` as a well.

Comment: Okay. I don't know much about sendToDeviceGroup but I should really use it as I use a Node.js server. I send messages the "old" way following this method - https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group#sending_downstream_messages_to_device_groups. But there's no reason why your example shouldn't work.

Comment: I see ... with the old way from what I saw you need to have the `Registration Keys` as well ... right ? ... i am thinking that maybe with `sendToDeviceGroup` i might need this as well ... so maybe that's why is not working ...

Comment: With the old way you just need the notification key of the device group - "Set the **to** parameter to the unique notification key for the device group"

Comment: Your key looks valid; starts with "APA91"; is the length 119?.  I just created a group and successfully sent a message using your code.

Comment: no ... the `notification_key` i get returned when creating the group is 140 in lenght ... am I missing some part of it ? or do I need to alter it in a way? -> also tried the "Old" way to send push via `http` as @camden_kid said he does and that works...with the same key

Comment: *Most* of the ones I have checked are 142 but some are different so I'm not sure where @BobSnyder gets 119 from. I would be interested to see any reference for that.

Comment: Hi John. Could you try sending a simple downstream message using a simple request towards the device group (see samples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase-cloud-messaging/8242/firebase-cloud-messaging#t=20170520055903182052)) and see if it would throw an error? If it did, could you include it in your post as well? Cheers! :)

Comment: hi @AL. it seems to work sending using your way as well, and as well using `HTTP` request in `Firebase Cloud Functions` ... the only way it does not work is sending it via `sendToDeviceGroup`

Comment: I wonder if I could send messages to device group using the send() method. Using the sendToDeviceGroup() method, I can't really put additional information for each OS.